# scheduling task execution in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, task, scheduling

How can I execute task in Java every x months?,
and how can I execute task in given days? (for example I want to execute my task every week in Sunday Tuesday and Saturday)

Thanks, Michal

Comment: This is very complex. You need to have some external storage to preserve when you last ran the task; otherwise, when you restart your Java process, it can only assume that it needs to wait x months, but then your task may never execute. Best is to use a third-party library like Quartz, or an external scheduler altogether that invokes your Java program every x months.

Comment: Thanks but I have to do that without quartz...

Comment: Why? That constraint doesn't seem logical

Comment: because my boss don't want me to use it .....

Comment: If your boss doesn't want the preferred Java framework for a purpose, then maybe he/she should suggest an alternative for you. Or, if (s)he has good reasons, ask for them and post them here to make your question and our answers useful for the whole Internet. Alternatively, if you think your boss is not being rational about this, you could ask a question on http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ on how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing easily with third party APIs. Quartz scheduler is one of it. Have a look over below links :

1) http://quartz-scheduler.org/ 
2) http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/